# Does LLVM have a tool for demangling Microsoft C++ mangling?

Tags: c++, llvm, name-mangling, demangler

I use LLVM on windows and I wonder if there is a command line tool to demangle MSVC C++ mangling. I am talking about command line tool like llvm-cxxfilt.

I see some [commits](https://reviews.llvm.org/D67851) in LLVM, but not sure if those are exposed as some tool or it is just C++ API.

I tried looking for llvm-undname mentioned in those commits in my LLVM install folder, but found nothing.

Comment: Doesn't Visual Studio's `undname.exe` work?  Does it have to be LLVM?

Comment: @Eljay did not know that exists, you can make it an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio comes with a command line tool called `undname.exe` which will undecorate (demangle) the name.

q.v. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 0):

Google shows me: https://reviews.llvm.org/D49552
as well as other useful links.

> Add a Microsoft Demangler library and utility.

So this feature was added in July of 2018 to the LLVM project.